# DataTables with (filter by) from json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I am trying make my filter works with json data from the server, someone could help me to do this?

I need filter by places: All, EUA,China, Spain

I am using: jquery.dataTables.js from: https://datatables.net

html:

```
  <div class=" dashboard">
  <div class="col-md-8 no-padding">
     <div class="form-group col-md-4 no-padding">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1" >
        <option value="Filter by">Filter by country </option>
         <option value="All">All</option>
         <option value="First name">China</option>
         <option value="Last name">EUA</option>
         <option value="Last name">Spain</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

<br>
<br>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Place</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
       dt.fnDestroy();
    } );

   $(document).ready(function () {
  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/crcCiZXZfm?indent=2';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: url,
    columns: [
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'place' }
    ]
  });
});
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ntcwust8/120/

Comment: Not really sure what suppose to happen when you chose filter by first name, all records have first name...

Comment: sorry you are right, I reformulate my question  I need the filter be working per places, so if filter by china just shows data from china If I choose Spain show the data from spain etc..., understand? thank you.

Comment: check this : https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: its that, but I need apply for the sample a posted with a select, can you help me? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/

Added the following code to your document.ready():

```
$('#sel1').change(function() {

  if (this.value === "All") {
    table
      .columns(1)
      .search('')
      .draw();
  }  

  else {
    table
      .columns(1)
      .search(this.value)
      .draw();
     }

});
```

So basically you tell your SELECT element to wait for its value to be changed. In order to show ALL, the .search() parameter is set to an empty string, which will return ALL. Otherwise the dropdown will trigger a table search on column(1) with the selected VALUE (not text!) of your SELECT and redraw your table.

*Note*: I also changed the value properties of your SELECT, since they were wrong in the beginning.

DataTables Documentation on column().search() can be found [HERE](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()).

Comment: `if (this.value === "All" || this.value === "Filter by")` will be better.

Comment: That is true, I missed that. Well, basically it would be a bit "cleaner" to simply remove the "Filter by" option, since it is no real option. I'd add a label to the SELECT element and let the first item be "All". Right now, selecting "Filter by" will return 0 results, obviously. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/1/

Comment: thank you , this is what I looking for, thank you very much, just 1 last question, I don't know why when I select the value in my code, the value goes to the search box, it is any way to make it not go to there? the funniest part is on jsfiddle not happen but locally in my code happen

Comment: That's interesting indeed. Maybe datatables is updating its own search textbox once the API call for search() was made. Did you compare if you are using the same datatables version, both on fiddle and locally?